# overloaded operator operator< in my class is not being used by STL max_element

Tags: c++

I have a vector of pointers to objects QActionDonald and I'm trying to find the object containing the highest expectedvalue_.  I have overloaded the operator< and I'm using the max_element method to obtain an iterator to the highest value but i always receive the end value which is not correct.
QActionDonald.h:

```
class QActionDonald
{
public:

double expectedvalue_;

bool operator < (const QActionDonald& other) const;

};
```

QActionDonald.cpp:

```
bool QActionDonald::operator< (const QActionDonald& other) const
{
    return expectedvalue_ < other.expectedvalue_;
}
```

otherClass:

```
std::vector<QActionDonald*> *actionList =  qValueDictionary[stateKey];

        std::vector<QActionDonald*>::iterator it = 
std::max_element(actionList->begin(), actionList->end());
```

Comment: Well, you're not comparing `QActionDonald`'s. You're comparing pointers to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's not, because your container has pointers, not objects.

For it to be used, you'll need `std::vector<QActionDonald>` or, if that's not subject to change, to provide a custom comparator to `std::max_element` that applies the correct logic (i.e. compare objects, not pointers).

Comment: Thanks.  So how do I get this to work than? I can't use the STL max_element if the container has pointers?  I basically have to do    std::max_element(actionList->begin(), actionList->end(), functionToCompaire())

Comment: @DonaldHerman you can, but you have to define your own function - i.e. `functionToCompare` that basically compares `*element1` and `*element2` (which are objects) as opposed to `element1` and `element2` which are pointers.

Comment: Can't I just dereference the pointer to implicitly call the overloaded operator method?